# Angular rxjs debounce to limit user from sending multiple requests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Basically my issue is that when the connection is slow the user was able to press the save button multiple times and multiple data are being save . This issue does not occur locally but on staging it does.

Although I already have set this.hasBeenSubmitted = true; when the request is done and [disabled] on the button based on the condition user was still able to click the button multiple times and could save multiple times which is wrong.

Some say that Angular rxjs debounce can be solution to this , can someone enlighten me regarding this one ? Thank you. And how would it help my issue based on the code below. Thanks.

## Code

```
save(): void {
    const create = this.requestFormService.createRequestData(this.form, this.respondents)
      .subscribe(
        (results: FeedbackRequest[]) => {
          this.hasBeenSubmitted = true;
        },
        (error) => {
          this.hasBeenSubmitted = false;
          this.handleInvalidFields(error, 'Failed to save the Feedback Request as draft. One or more fields contain invalid values. Input a valid value to proceed.');
          this.messageDialogService.show('Failed to save the Feedback Request as draft. One or more fields contain invalid values. Input a valid value to proceed.', true);
          create.unsubscribe();
        }
      );
  }
```

## html

```
 <button [disabled]="form.invalid || (!duplicateMode && !form.dirty) || (!editMode) || hasBeenSubmitted"
        mat-raised-button *ngIf="form" (click)="save()" type="submit">
        <ng-container>
          <span>SAVE</span>
        </ng-container>
      </button>
```

Comment: Why not set the disabled flag before you execute the async method? This will prevent additional button clicks regardless of how long the request takes. You can always re-enable in success or error.

Comment: you mean before the create()?

Comment: Yes, this is common in terms of disabling buttons. It’s not dependent on the length of time to get the response from the server. It gets disabled immediately.

Comment: check my button condition sir again I have update it

Comment: Okay sure, but update method save to set hasBeenSubmitted to true before executing create()

Comment: All I have to do is open up multiple tabs, and you are back to square one. You can't resolve this purely by limiting concurrent requests within an _instance_ of a web client.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to restrict the user to hit save multiple times, and you said you already have the disabled condition applied.

Could you try to rewrite your save button like the following.

```
save(): void {
    this.hasBeenSubmitted = true;
    const create = this.requestFormService.createRequestData(this.form, this.respondents)
      .pipe(
       take(1), 
       finalized(this.hasBeenSubmitted = false),
       ),
       catchError((err) =>{
          this.hasBeenSubmitted = false;
          this.handleInvalidFields(error, 'Failed to save the Feedback Request as 
          draft. One or more fields contain invalid values. Input a valid value to proceed.');
          this.messageDialogService.show('Failed to save the Feedback Request as 
          draft. One or more fields contain invalid values. Input a valid value to proceed.', true);
         create.unsubscribe();
      })
      .subscribe(
        (results: FeedbackRequest[]) => {

        }
      );
  }
```

The major thing I change is executing `this.hasBeenSubmitted = true;` before create call.

I hope it helps.

Comment: what is pipe , take , finalized for ?

Comment: A pipe is for chaining other operators it is mandatory to use from rx6 onwards, Finalized will be called once the stream is completed

Comment: Now when you say code does not work, could you elaborate on what it is not working. I mean any compile-time error or the button does not disabled?